# .NET System.Security.Cryptography Key Derivation Question (AES/Rijndael)

Tags: c#, .net, aes, rijndael

When using the methods GenerateKey(), CreateEncryptor(Byte[], Byte[]), or CreateEncryptor() found in System.Security.Cryptography.Rijndael or System.Security.Cryptography.Aes class, how are the the keys generated?

1. Does it follow the methods used in [RFC-2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)? I can only make an assumption that it does follow RFC-2898 since Rfc2898DeriveBytes is also a class in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the GenerateIV Method and the GenerateKey Method just generate a sequence of random bytes of the required length. They do not use a KDF.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the sequences of random bytes are crypto-strength, and not just taken from the output of `System.Random`.

Comment: dtb, Do you suppose GenerateIV Method uses a CSPRBG? (cyrptographically secure pseudo random bit generator)

Comment: @Maeslstrom Yamato: I'm pretty sure that it uses `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` internally to generate the random bytes. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx